# Selection & identification of child node in TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have created a treeview in my xaml.

```
<TreeView Name="exportTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="350" >
<TreeView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="layersTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <CheckBox Foreground="White" IsChecked="{Binding IsToBeExported}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Style="{StaticResource baseStyle}" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="objectTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LayersList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=layersTemplate}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="15" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <CheckBox Foreground="White" IsChecked="{Binding IsToBeExported}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Style="{StaticResource baseStyle}" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjectList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=objectTemplate}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <CheckBox Foreground="White" IsChecked="{Binding IsToBeExported}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Style="{StaticResource baseStyle}" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

The tree structure is like below. Each Parent can have any number of children & each Child can have any number of Grandchildren. Multiple selection is allowed too.

```
Parent
  -Child
    --Grandchild
```

I have checkboxes for all levels. I am not getting how to access its nodes individually and also how to use the tree data.

In my VM class, I set the datacontext of this TreeView to a 3 class list like below:

```
public class MProject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsToBeExported { get; set; }
    public List<MWorkObject> ObjectList { get; set; }
}

public class MWorkObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsToBeExported { get; set; }
    public List<MLayer> LayersList { get; set; }
}

public class MLayer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsToBeExported { get; set; }
}
```

My requirement is:

1. Selecting the parent should select all its child and grandchild.
2. How to identify in the code which item is selected ? Need it to do further processing.

Please help.

Comment: Where is your IsToBeExported in each class?

Comment: Missed while pasting the code here. Edited now.

Comment: Use `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan: when, where & how ? Sorry, I am new to WPF n C#.

Comment: Do you mean select the tree item(it is highlighted) or check box?

Comment: @Rekshino: User selects the checkboxes not the tree item. The details of selected ones needs to be passed on to the code for further processing. Comment if I have done anything wrong in my above treeview code too pls.

Comment: http://www.journeyintocode.com/2013/04/mvvm-binding-to-treeviewselecteditem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for your classes. Then

1. in setter of IsToBeExported in MProject handle  all children (set
   IsToBeExported to what you need). The binding makes the change
   visible in tree
2. if IsToBeExported set to true, then it is selected

Example:

```
public class ViewBase :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {       
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}

public class MProject : ViewBase
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }
    }
    private string _name;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I am working on it. If more doubts, I will come back here.